# Why does not indexOf give the right result from unicode?

Tags: java, unicode, indexof

I do not understand why I do not get the right result if I use the indexOf with Unicode representation of a char?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strg = "Dog?Cat";
        System.out.println("String: " + strg);
        System.out.println("Char: " + strg.indexOf('?'));
        System.out.println("String: " + strg.indexOf(new String("?")));
        System.out.println("Sign: " + String.valueOf('\u0134'));
        System.out.println("Unicode: " + strg.indexOf(String.valueOf('\u0134')));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
String: Dog?Cat
Char: 3
String: 3
Sign: ?
Unicode: -1   --> Why is it -1 ?! Why not 3 ?
```

Could You please help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is the encoding of your environment?

Comment: Because your string does not contain the character [U+0134](https://codepoints.net/U+0134). Note: This character is not the question mark character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.valueOf('\u0134')` is not the `'?'` character. `System.out.println` prints `'?'` for many unprintable characters (such as `'\u0134'`), but your `"Dog?Cat"` String doesn't contain the `'\u0134'` character.

This would give you the expected 3 :

```
String strg = "Dog?Cat";
System.out.println("Unicode: " + strg.indexOf(String.valueOf('\u003f')));
```

Comment: Thank You, yes, I know why now!